Kubuntu 24.04 LTS everything scaled after installing nvidia drivers
I installed Kubuntu 24.04 today and it looked fine. Then I installed Nvidia drivers using ppa repository and sudo apt install nvidia-driver-555 and everything just scaled and looks big after that and I am not able to fix it. My global scale is at 100% which on changing I noticed doesn't affect the screen.

I use Xorg11 and I have no idea how to fix this. My Google Chrome also looks so big at 100%. xrandr --dpi 96 or xrandr --dpi 144 doesn't seem to fix the problem for me. After I reboot it just resets back to scaled.

If you search this site you will see using the PPA driver is not a good idea.

@David but i wanted to install latest nvidia driver and that was the only way. I looked up a bit more but its mainly problem with the nvidia driver ig

Why do you need the "latest" Nvidia driver? Is there any problem with the default driver offered by Ubuntu? Try changing the driver with the command sudo kubuntu-driver-manager

This is a more general problem of this version of kubuntu. You cannot rescale your display. I'm using Kubuntu 24.04 on a Dell Inspiron laptop with an Intel Arc (no proprietary drivers) graphics and rescaling has no effect.
The only work around as I am aware of is to replace your resolution for an higher one or set the DPI in the font settings panel
